# Xcode 6 added a gap on my collection view

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, xcode6

I previously was working in Xcode 5, but I just switched to Xcode 6.  My app mostly still functions properly but I noticed that my collection views now have a gap between the items.  The white gap between the items is in the picture below.  The gap is actually covering some of the image too, you can see part of a blue circle on the items in the lower right hand corner.  Everything was working perfectly in Xcode 5.  Any advice?  Thanks.

I am using the following to dynamically set the item sizes in code.

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGFloat viewHeight = self.contentItemCollectionView.bounds.size.height;

    ContentItems* ci = (ContentItems*)object;

    if([ci.itemId intValue] == STORE_ITEM_DEFAULT) {
        return CGSizeMake(viewHeight,viewHeight);
    }

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.collectionItemWidth, self.collectionItemHeight);
    return size;
}
```

[image]

Before Xcode 6 it looked like this:

[image]

Comment: You're using the following... what? I think something may have gone missing between your screen and StackOverflow.

Comment: It looks like `-collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` is returning the value `136` for each cell in the top and bottom images.

Comment: It is returning 75 x 100 in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subclassed UICollectionViewLayout and created my collection view.  This way I could control the entire creation of the collection view.